# #1045 Cannot log in to the MySQL server on ec2 instance

Tags: mysql, amazon-ec2, phpmyadmin

I created a new amazon EC2 instance and insalled LAMP + phpmyadmin.

PhyMyAdmin is working by when I try to login into it using host I am getting the error 
 #1045 Cannot log in to the MySQL server.

```
Here are my config settings 
/* Authentication type */
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['auth_type'] = 'cookie';
/* Server parameters */
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['host'] = 'xxx-xx-xxx-xx-xxx.ap.southeast-1.compute.amazonaws.com'
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['connect_type'] = 'tcp';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['compress'] = false;
/* Select mysqli if your server has it */
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['extension'] = 'mysqli';
/* User for advanced features */
// $cfg['Servers'][$i]['controluser'] = 'pma';
```

Any idea why this isnt working?

Comment: Is the "compute.amazonaws.com" not supposed to have a single quote after?

Comment: yes it does...sorry my bad in copy pasting the code

Comment: PHPMyAdmin may be "running" from the local context, i.e. it is already on the server (localhost).  Make sure your remote access settings allow your IP to connect.  By default there are set to localhost only.  Try with MySQL workbench to under "Users and Privileges" to make sure the valid user/ip configuration is met, i.e. you are allowed.

Comment: how do I access workbench on EC2 instance?

Comment: And I can connect to phpmyadmin. I am not able to log in

Comment: Are you able to log in using PHPMyAdmin and see your databases and run sql?